# Create a PhoneGap App: Hello World compiling error

Tags: phonegap

We have given a task as per below screen -

[image: Task]

We had written code as -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' gap:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>My First App</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">connecting</p>
            <p class="event received">connected once device is ready.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When we compiling it then getting error as -

> - [0;36mConnecting to localhost on port 9515...
>
> [0m
>
> ⚠ [0;31mError connecting to localhost on port 9515.[0m
>
> [1;31m_________________________________________________[0m
>
> [1;31mTEST FAILURE:[0m [0;31m1[0m error during execution;
> [0;31m0[0m tests failed, [0;32m0[0m passed [0;90m(412ms)[0m
>
> [0;31m ✖ home.spec[0m
>
> [0;31mAn error occurred while retrieving a new session: "session not
> created: Chrome version must be between 71 and 75"[0m
>
> [0;90mError: An error occurred while retrieving a new session:
> "session not created: Chrome version must be between 71 and 75"[0m
>
> [0;31m  Error: An error occurred while retrieving a new session:
> "session not created: Chrome version must be between 71 and 75"[0m
>
> [0;90m   [0m
>
> [0;36m   SKIPPED:[0m
>
> - should display Heading My First App.
> - should display connected once device is ready.

Please let us know expert advice what could be the reason for it.

Comment: It's saying your version of Chrome is too old (currenty, it's 89). 75 came out in June 2019 (and v71 came out in December 2018).

Comment: Actual it is not chrome version , it is chrome version on playground.  How to find it?